# What is the current status of Killeen’s probability of replication?

Tags: p-value, references, reproducible-research, repeatability

Killeen (1) published several papers about P-rep. It can be easily computed from a p-value (for a two-group comparison) and has an easy interpretation. It is the estimated probability that future repeat experiments (same sample size, same assumptions, only random sampling differs) will result in a difference that goes in the same direction (so the difference has the same sign). That includes *all* differences in the same direction, including tiny ones, so includes some future studies that result in a large p-value.

Lecoutre (2) went further and improved the equations, and showed how P-rep fits in the Bayesian world. It seems like a useful way to think about reproducibility. It is a simple function of the p-value so can't provide additional information, but it seems like a useful way to interpret results.

My question is whether this value (P-rep) has been used much in various fields (beyond psychology) and found to be useful. I can't find citations in the last decade. Do statisticians agree it is useful, or find that it is somehow incorrect or misleading?

Another minor question is: Lecoutre et al mentioned a webpage with equations, code and an Excel file. But that URL no longer works. Please let me know if it can be found!

1. Killeen, P. R. An Alternative to Null-Hypothesis Significance Tests. Psychol Sci 16, 345–353 (2004). DOI: 10.1111/j.0956-7976.2005.01538.x
2. Lecoutre, B., Lecoutre, M.-P. & Poitevineau, J. Killeen’s Probability of Replication and Predictive Probabilities: How to Compute, Use, and Interpret Them. Psychol Methods 15, 158–171 (2010). DOI: 10.1037/a0015915

Comment: Seems to me that the Prep suffers badly from the assumption that the chosen statistical model is a close match to the actual data generating and sampling systems. That assumption is very often optimistic, and has to be used twice when applying a Prep to real world data. Thinking about that assumption might be more useful than calculating the Prep...

Comment: @MichaelLew. I don't quite follow. "Twice"??

Comment: Twice because the relevance of the original p-value to any real-world replication relies on the model-real world match, and then the relevance of the Prep to a potential real-world replication relies on the same match.

Comment: [This post](https://probonostats.wordpress.com/2007/09/16/p-rep-and-the-myth-of-rational-science/#more-27) and [this earlier one](https://probonostats.wordpress.com/2007/09/15/p-rep-mathematical-error-pure-and-simple/) claim to have found a fundamental flaw in Killeen's paper. I haven't dug into the argument, nor into Killeen's original paper.

Comment: Thanks @StephanKolassa. That is exactly what I needed to know. Why don't you turn your comment into an answer?

Comment: Here is the paper that refutes the usefulness of p-rep:
https://www.ejwagenmakers.com/2009/IversonEtAl2009PBR.pdf

Comment: Thank you, good to hear my comment was useful. I can't really turn it into an answer since I did not read either one of these papers in sufficient depth to really comment on them. Perhaps you would like to self-answer based on that paper? I do think this would be useful for later readers.

Comment: @StephanKolassa. Thanks. Done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A comment by @StephanKolassa let me answer my own question. There are serious doubts about the usefulness (and correctness) of p-rep.  Here are critiques and discussions of p-rep:

R.R. Macdonald, [Commentary: Why replication probabilities depend on prior probability distributions: A rejoinder to Killeen (2005)](https://psycnet.apa.org/record/2005-15678-016) Psychological Science, 16(12), 1007–1008. "Any simulation of replication probabilities has to incorporate a distribution for [prior probabilities]. Killeen's approach ignores such distributions and as a result, seems appropriate only when there is no relevant prior information."

P.R. Killeen: [Replicability, Confidence, and Priors](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC1440522/), Psychol Sci. 2005 Dec; 16(12): 1009–1012. Killeen responds to some critics.

Gat, Y.,  [p-rep, mathematical error, pure and simple](https://probonostats.wordpress.com/2007/09/15/p-rep-mathematical-error-pure-and-simple/) 2007. "It turns out that Killeen really is utterly and honestly mistaken about his proposed statistic, the p-rep. His entire analysis is wrong because of a relatively simple mathematical error."

G.J. Iverson, M. D. Lee, and E-J Wagenmakers, [prep misestimates the probability of replication](https://www.ejwagenmakers.com/2009/IversonEtAl2009PBR.pdf) Psychonomic Bulletin & Review
2009, 16 (2), 424-429. doi:10.3758/PBR.16.2.424. "Our results show
that, over any plausible series of experiments, the true probabilities of replication will be very different from those predicted by
prep. We discuss some basic problems in the formulation of prep
that are responsible for its poor performance, and conclude that
prep is not a useful statistic for psychological science."